# WPF DataGrid ScrollIntoView doesn't scroll to requested row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollview

I am using WPF DataGrid which has ~50 rows. I am using MVVM pattern.
User can search for some text in a row and datagrid should highlight the row (not necessarily select the row) and scroll to that row if that row is not visible on screen yet.

Trimmed XAML code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataView,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="myDataGrid"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="Generate_Column" 
          CurrentCell="{Binding DGCurrentCell, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

Code Behind:

```
public void ScrollToItem(object gridObj, object item)
{
    myDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        myDataGrid.Focus();
        myDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }));
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    protected override bool FindItem(string searchString)
    {
        bool itemFound=false;
        DataRow[] rows = this.MyDataTable.Select(searchString);
        if (rows.Count() > 0)
        {
            itemFound = true;
            //Scroll to the first row which is a match
            (this.View as SCDataGridView).ScrollToItem(this, rows[0]);
        }
        return itemFound;
    }
```

ScrollToItem API is called if item is found, but scrollviewer never scrolls to that item.
I tried various combinations for the following fields but nothing has helped me so far:

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility- Auto or Disabled
VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit- Pixel or Item
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode- Standard or Recycling
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing - True or False
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue why `ScrollIntoView` didnt work for me. `ScrollIntoView` requires the exact object type bound to ItemsSource. In my case ItemsSource was bound to MyDataView and every item was of type DataRowView. When calling `ScrollIntoView`, i was passing DataRow object and hence it was not working.

Once I passed correct DataRowView object, it worked. I didnt have to set the SelectedItem to this item (as I didnt want to select the item, just scroll to the searched item).
Following is the working sample - I didnt have to call UpdateLayout() or beginInvoke

```
public void ScrollToItem(object gridObj, int itemIdx)
{
    myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView((this.DataContext).MyDataView[itemIdx], null);
}
```

Another important thing i realized while debugging this is that to set Virtualization on or off on a DataGrid/List etc., one should use `ScrollViewer.CanScrollContent` instead of `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit` property as `ScrollViewer.CanScrollContent` is passed to scrollviewer which is actually responsible for implementing virtualization.

Again, true/false value of `ScrollViewer.CanScrollContent` has no impact on `ScrollIntoView` functioning.

Hope this helps someone.

RDV

Answer (score 1):

Slight difference in how I have my similar version to find and force datagrid to scroll into position...  Minor, but different none-the-less.

```
public void ScrollToItem(object gridObj, object item)
{
    myDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
    {
        myDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item, null);
        SelectedRow = item;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had hidden columns, which seemed to cause the DataGrid to be unable to find and scroll to the correct row, even after calling `UpdateLayout()`. My solution was to specify a known visible column as a second parameter.

```
UpdateLayout();
PresetsDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(preset, PresetsDataGrid.Columns[0]);
```